# How to return a http get request from rest api with angular factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to return a http get request from a rest api url inside a factory. But it's not returning data but instead the function. When I use console log inside the controller it show the whole function.

```
MyApp.factory('userFactory', function($http) {

    var factory = [];

    factory.users = function(){
        $http({
            url: '/test/users',
            method: 'GET'
        })
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            factory.users = response;

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            factory.users = response;
        });

        return factory.users;
    };

    return factory;

});
```

Comment: You are using a slightly different method than I use (`$http.get`), but I think the problem is that you need to return the $http promise.  Try `factory.users = function() { return $http(...` and we can go from there.

Comment: you should be returning `response.data`, but you can't change a function into an object inside the function itself... (i.e. `factory.users` is a function, and so inside this function, trying to assign `factory.users` to a different object isn't going to work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do the same thing in my projects. Check out the repo here:
https://github.com/ahmadabdul3/mean-flapperNews/tree/master/public/Index/angular

the httpService is my http handler. Then you can look at the postsService, see my getAllPosts function

basically like the comments say, you have to return a promise and handle it in the controller

so you do it like this:

```
function getAllPosts() {
        httpService.baseGet(httpUrls.posts)
        .then(function(data) {
            angular.copy(data, posts);
            posts.push({title: 'post test', link: '', upvotes: 3, comments: []});
        }, function(data) {
            httpService.handleError(data);
        });
    }
```

and have the http service do the work:

```
angular.module('httpService', [])
.factory('httpService', httpService);

httpService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

function httpService($http, $q) {
    var serv = this;
    var methods = {
        httpGet : 'GET',
        httpPost : 'POST',
        httpPut : 'PUT',
        httpDelete : 'DELETE'
    };
    function baseGet(url) {
        return $http.get(url).then(
                function (result) {
                    return result.data;
                },
                function (result) {
                    return $q.reject(result);
                }
                );
    }
    function httpWithParams(url, method, data) {

        return $http({
                url: url,
                method: method,
                params: data,
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }).then(
                function (result) {
                    console.log(result.data);
                    return result.data;
                },
                function (result) {
                    return $q.reject(result);
                }
            );
    }
    function handleError(error) {
            console.log(error);
    }

    return {
        baseGet: baseGet,
        httpWithParams: httpWithParams,
        handleError: handleError,
        methods: methods
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See $http docs - it returns a promise so you need to handle this accordingly. You also seem to have some conflicts in your variable naming which will not help the issue.

I suggest following [johnpapa's angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) - and in this case the data services rule. You have most of this already.

You could either handle the promise in the controller like below - or use a setter (getUser / setUsers on factory to share between controllers/concerns).

```
  MyApp.factory('userFactory', function($http) {
    // Expose public API first, use func notation
      return { 
          getUsers: getUsers,
      };

      function getUsers(){
          return $http.get('/test/users');
      }
 });

 MyApp.controller('UserController', function(userFactory) {
    // bindables up top
    vm.users = [];

    activate();

    //separate activation logic / promise resolution
    function activate(){
        userFactory.getUsers().then(function(users){
          vm.users = users.data;
        });
    }    
});
```

Comment: Got it working by using the code from above. Also have read through some of johnpapa style guide. Very useful thanks!